# Запуск SWF файла локально через браузер посредством кода

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chromium

У меня есть цель через браузер локально открывать Флэш файлы, на данный момент у меня есть такой код:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript:(function(){document.querySelector('embed').src = 'file:///'+prompt('Укажите путь к файлу', ''); document.body.appendChild(document.querySelector('embed'));})()" value="Указать путь (скопируй заранее)">
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript:(function(){document.querySelector('embed').width = prompt('Укажите ширину', '500px - 500пикселей, 100% - 100% страницы');})()" value="Указать ширину">
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript:(function(){document.querySelector('embed').height = prompt('Укажите высоту', '500px - 500пикселей, 100% - 100% страницы');})()" value="Указать высоту">
        <embed width="100%" height="100%" src="file:///null">
    </body>
</html>
```

В общем-то он делает то что мне нужно, но хотелось бы оптимизировать способ интегрирования Флэш файла, чтобы не мучиться с копированием пути вручную. Я полагаю, что тут может помочь Drag & Drop способ, но понять как его использовать для получения полного пути к файлу или сразу для интеграции файла - у меня не получается (и причём туплю я с этим довольно долго, оттого и обращаюсь сюда)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня такой вариант. Просто файл перетаскиваешь на страницу и он динамически добавляется на неё. Если файлов несколько то добавляются все.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $("html").on("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('dragging');
  });

  $("html").on("dragleave", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).removeClass('dragging');
  });

$("html").on("drop", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();  
  event.stopPropagation();
  var myfiles = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
  for (var ix = 0; ix < myfiles.length ; ix++) {
  var node=document.createElement('object');
    node.type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    node.data=URL.createObjectURL(myfiles[ix])
    node.width="300"
    node.height="300"
    document.body.appendChild(node);
 }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```